# How to remove these Facebook Pixel from Shopify Store?

Tags: facebook, shopify, pixel, liquid

I have a shopify store that is loading unwanted Facebook Pixels, probably installed in my store by old apps.
The problem is I want my store without any pixel, I have removed my pixel from the Online Store > Preferences and checked most of my liquid files for pixel codes and I have found nothing.

But the Facebook Pixel Helper still says my store has 2 facebook pixel installed. I dont know how to remove them, since I cant find them,

[My store link](http://trendotrends.com)

I appreciate any help from you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem, the support of Shopify had finally found that this pixel was injected by mailchimp